# C - convert from string to unsigned int

Tags: c, converters, type-conversion, unsigned-integer

How do I convert from string to unsigned int?

I know that `strtoul()` converts from string to `unsigned long int`, but I want normal `int` and not `long int`.

I haven't been able to find a function that does that.

Comment: There's `atoi` but it has no error checking the same way `strtoul` have. And you can use `strtoul` and just check that the value is lower or equal  to `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: `sscanf` does not necessarily perform correct range checking for types smaller than `long`.

Comment: yes, standards do not specify the ERANGE error.(use GCC)

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen: This question is about C, not about C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I want normal [unsigned] int and not long [unsigned] int.

You want to use [`strtoul()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtoul.3.html), assign it to a `long unsigned int`, test the result for being in the range of `[0..UINT_MAX]`  and if this is the case assign the `long unsigned int` to an `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested and found out that `strtoul` converts to a value equal to `UINT_MAX` so I guess this works.

Comment: Probably because you program on Windows.  On this platform `sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(unsigned long)`, so `strtoul` indeed does the job.  On more consistent 64 bit platforms, alk's solution is far superior.